# Android:Dynamic add Edit Text Box in a Linear Layouts?

Tags: android

Hi
          I have a Linear Layout its  `orientation="vertical` and it contains  3 Edit Box By default .When i click **Add Button** ,I want to create next Edit Box Dynamically ,under the previous Edit box .When click **Save button**  i want to get all contents of edit box .

please Help me

Augustine

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new EditText and then add it to the linear layout using ViewGroup.addView.  Make sure that when you add the view, you create a new LinearLayout.LayoutParams.  As for getting the contents, you can use ViewGroup.getChildAt() to fetch out the EditTexts.